# Camera body with autofocus

Tags: nikon, autofocus

Can I buy a Nikon camera body that already has autofocus, then purchase any non-autofocus Nikon lens and be able autofocus simply from the body itself?

Comment: Josh, you can merge your two accounts at http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0):

No. Modern autofocus lenses require motor in lens, older were motorized from body but were marked as AF capable. If lens is non AF it cannot use AF.

Comment: This is a correct (and succinct) answer, but please don't answer questions which are clearly duplicates — it just muddles things up. Instead, provide your answer to the question linked above. Thanks!